# Dehydrating hydrated Magnesium chloride

Tags: metallurgy

I came to know that hydrated Magnesium chloride $\ce{MgCl2.6H2O}$ is dehydrated not directly by heating as it gets hydrolysed to $\ce{MgO}$ . But instead it is dehydrated by passing through $\ce{HCl}$ gas at $\pu{650 K}$. But on doing so how is formation of $\ce{MgO}$ prevented?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is prevented by shifting the equilibrium

$$\ce{MgCl2(s) + H2O(s,g) <=> MgO(s) + 2 HCl(g)}$$

to the left, by removal of $\ce{H2O}$ and providing enough $\ce{HCl}$.

Comment: Basically I agree, but do we get MgO? Could form the hydroxide or even Mg(OH)Cl.

Comment: At 650  K and in HCl stream? I doubt that. Mg(OH)2 reportedly decomposes at 350°C. I bet Mg(OH)Cl would not held the stand much better, even if I do not reject possibility of temporary a/o minor occurrence.